# Cannot set Ethernet adapter to 1Gbps with powerline

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-adapter, powerline-networking

I have recently set up a new computer with an Ethernet adapter that supports up to 1 Gbps.  I have a 600Mbps optical fibre connection with a set of PLCs (TL-WPA4220KIT) to run a wired connection from the router to the computer.  Both ends are connected by a Category 7 Ethernet cable.

When I try to change the speed and duplex of the adapter to 1 Gbps, the adapter becomes disabled and says that I do not have any cable plugged in.

Image of the adapter after changing the speed:
[image: Image of the adapter after changing speed, "Cable de red desconectado" means "Network cable disconnected."]
*("Cable de red desconectado" means "Network cable disconnected")*

To make the Ethernet work again, I need to set the speed and duplex to another option that isn't the 1 Gbps one.  The adapter is an Intel Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V.  I am using Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?
I have looked in other posts but nothing has worked for me.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by  _'a set of PLCs'_ so I searched for the part number. What I found was a [device](https://www.tp-link.com/us/service-provider/powerline-adapter/tl-wpa4220kit/) that uses power lines to extend a network, and that doesn't support Gigabit Ethernet. Is this what you have?

Answer (score 2):

The TP-Link TL-WPA4220KIT **only supports up to 100Mbps Ethernet** ([100BASE-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet)), so by trying to force 1Gbps ([1000BASE-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet)), transmission fails and the link drops.

<sup><sub>Source: [https://www.tp-link.com/us/service-provider/powerline-adapter/tl-wpa4220kit/#specifications](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624004835/https://www.tp-link.com/us/service-provider/powerline-adapter/tl-wpa4220kit/#specifications)</sub></sup>

[image: TL-WPA4220KIT Hardware Features]

---

Even though the powerline adapter claims to support up to 300Mbps, that number refers to the theoretical maximum Wi-Fi link speed.

The adapter also suggests that it can transmit wired up to 600Mbps (AV600), but [in practice, you would not get anywhere near that speed](https://superuser.com/a/1125578/83694).